# Pi Day, Pi Minute, or Pi Second?

Tags: code-golf, date, pi

In this challenge you will need to determine whether it's Pi Day, Pi Minute, or Pi Second.

Because Pi is irrational, it wants your code to be as short as possible.

## Examples

**No input is provided**, your program should use the system time. I've just added it for clarity

```
March 14, 2016 0:00:00
Pi Day
December 25, 2015 3:14:45
Pi Minute
December 29, 2015 0:03:14
Pi Second
January 1, 2016 0:00:00
<No Output>
```

### What is Pi Day / Minute / Second

- `Pi Day` is when the month is March, and the date is the 14th
- `Pi Minute` is when the hour is 3, and the minute is 14
- `Pi Second` is when the minute is 3, and the second is 14
- `Pi Day` should be preferred instead of `Pi Minute` or `Pi Second`, and `Pi Minute` should be preferred instead of `Pi Second`.
- For this challenge you should use 12-hour time (15:14 == 3:14). The date/time used to determine the `Pi Day/Minute/Second` should be based on **system time**.

### Scoring & Bonus

**-15 byte Bonus:** If you print `"No Pi Time"` when it's not Pi time.

---

As always, [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: I don't think Costco allows you to purchase the mathematical constant pi at any time of the year.

Comment: You've changed it to regular pie. That's also false because you can get pie from Costco all year.

Comment: @AlexA. Hmm, weird I can never find it in the summer...

Comment: Because pi is infinitely long and you want to be passive-aggressive?

Comment: Would `"Pi day"`, `"Pi month"`, etc. be accepted also?

Comment: @ZachGates `Pi month` doesn't exist but to answer your question, no, the output must be the correct case

Comment: I went to Costco today - they were closed.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma why did you go

Comment: @undergroundmonorail To buy pies

Comment: @AlexA. Sure you can - any time you buy a tire or any other circular object, you're buying 2π.

Comment: I think you can't have Pi Minute and Pi Second at the same time, so there's no point in preferring either one.

Comment: Nothing special if it's March 14 2015 9:26:53?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma but they were closed

Comment: @immibis Or March 14 1592 6:53:58?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CJam, 41 bytes

```
et[3E]#"
Pi Day

Pi Minute
Pi Second
"N/=
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=et%5B3E%5D%23%22%0APi%20Day%0A%0APi%20Minute%0APi%20Second%0A%22N%2F%3D) Alternatively [use this link](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B2016%203%2014%2017%2045%2013%20458%201%20-3600000%5D%0A%5B3E%5D%23%22%0APi%20Day%0A%0APi%20Minute%0APi%20Second%0A%22N%2F%3D) to stub the result of `et` for easier testing.

#### Explanation

```
et   e# Get the current datetime as an array with the following elements:
     e#   - Year
     e#   - Month
     e#   - Day
     e#   - Hour
     e#   - Minute
     e#   - Second
     e#   - Millisecond
     e#   - Weekday
     e#   - Tickrate or something.
[3E] e# Push the array [3 14].
#    e# Find the position of this subarray in the current datetime array. Let's see
     e# what results we can get:
     e#   - Year 3 is in the past and there is no 14th month, so we can't get 0.
     e#   - Pi day will give result 1.
     e#   - Day 3, hour 14 would give 2.
     e#   - Pi minute will give result 3.
     e#   - Pi second will give result 4.
     e#   - Second 3, millisecond 14 would give 5.
     e#   - Weekday and tickrate won't be 14, so we'll never get 6 or 7.
     e#   - If [3 14] isn't found at all we get -1.
"\Pi Day\\Pi Minute\Pi Second\"
     e# Push this string (with linefeeds instead of backslashes.
N/   e# Split into lines.
=    e# Select the corresponding element. The non-existent "pi hour" and "pi millisecond"
     e# would map to empty strings as well as the -1.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>114</strike> 112 - 15 = 97 bytes

```js
x=>['Pi Day','Pi Minute','Pi Second'].find((x,i)=>[/ar 14/,/(03|15):14:/,/03:14/][i].test(Date()))||'No Pi Time'
```

**Ungolfed:**

```js
x=>
['Pi Day', 'Pi Minute', 'Pi Second']  // array of outputs
.find(                                // find first element in the array
    (x, i)=>                          // which returns truthy for this function
    [/ar 14/, /(03|15):14:/, /03:14/] // array of regex patterns
    [i]                               // get corresponding regex based on index
    .test(Date())                     // test it against current date, date is automatically cast to string
) || 'No Pi Time'                     // if no result, then return "No Pi Time"
```

Thanks for -2 bytes [@edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65)

Comment: Could be `Date()` instead of `new Date`

Comment: `'Pi '+['Day','Minute','Second'].find((x,i)=>`................

Comment: @wizzwizz4 this won't work. If it's not Pi time, it returns `"Pi undefined"`

Comment: Would a check for undefined be shorter than 6 chars?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 its less bytes to just include `"Pi "` in all three strings :)

Comment: @nderscore It's fewer bytes to say `nderscore` than `underscore`.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <s>125</s> 124 chars

```ruby
i=[*[(t=Time.new).month,t.day,t.hour,t.min,t.sec].each_cons(2)].index [3,14];i&&$><<['Pi Day','','Pi Minute','Pi Second'][i]
```

Alas, the cleverer `%i[month day hour min sec].map{|x|Time.new.send x}` is longer.

The key here is the use of `each_cons` to avoid repetition (see the last few lines of the explanation below).

```ruby
i=                          # send i (index) to...
[*                          # convert to array (splat)...
 [
  (t=Time.new).month,       # the current month...
  t.day,t.hour,t.min,t.sec  # etc... (duh)
 ]
 .each_cons(2)              # each consecutive two elements
]                           # [[month, day], [day, hour], [hour, min], etc]
.index [3,14];              # first occurrence of [3, 14]
i&&                         # shorthand for "if i"...
$><<                        # output...
[
 'Pi Day',                  # [month=3, day=14] is Pi Day
 '',                        # [day=3, hour=14] isn't anything
 'Pi Minute',               # [hour=3, min=14] is Pi Minute
 'Pi Second'                # [min=3, sec=14] is Pi Second
][i]                        # index by index (obviously)
```

Comment: @Cole And what will you do with the second element?

Comment: Why isn't Pi Hour anything. What's wrong with 2 in the afternoon, tomorrow?

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, `[(p='Pi ')+Day','',p+'Minute',p+'Second']` is longer.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, <s>219</s> <s>186</s> 183 Bytes (198-15)

<sub>I tried</sub>

Ungolfed:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
output = ['Pi Day', 'Pi Minute', 'Pi Second', 'No Pi Time']

if now.month == 3 and now.day == 14:
    print output[0]
elif now.hour == 2 and now.minute == 13:
    print output[1]
elif now.minute = 2 and now.second == 13:
    print output[2]
else:
    print output[3]
```

Golfed:

```
from datetime import *
n=datetime.now()
a=n.minute
if n.month==3and n.day==14:print'Pi Day'
elif n.hour==2and a==13:print'Pi Minute'
elif a==2and n.second==13:print'Pi Second'
else:print'No Pi Time'
```

Comment: `from datetime import*;n=datetime.now()` is shorter. Also, there's no point in indexing into an array when you're printing constant strings.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 That's true :)

Comment: Shorter even: https://paste.ee/p/ebcSh

Comment: Made by swapping if/elses with [else,if][statement].

Comment: The latter numbers are wrong (2:13 instead of 3:14), and the 12-hour clock requirement isn't met. (Seems to apply to some other answers too) You can also get it shorter by indexing the result of `time.localtime()`; it comes down to 148-15 bytes (without the 12-hour fix). The 12-hour thing is unfortunate though; without it you could easily get it down to 129-15 bytes: `import time;x=3,14;T=time.localtime();print{1:'Pi Day',3:'Pi Minute',4:'Pi Second'}.get((zip(T,T[1:])+[x]).index(x),'No Pi Time')` (and 118-15 bytes on Python 3, by converting to bytes and using find, which makes things simpler)

Answer (score 4):

### Japt, 78 - 15 = 63 bytes

```
D=Ð)g ¥3©Df ¥E?"Pi Day":Dd %C¥3©Dc ¥E?`Pi M©e`:Dc ¥3©Db ¥E?`Pi SeÖ:No Pi Te
```

Pretty straightforward - just checks the date for every case.

Explanation:

- `D=Ð)g` get the current date (`Ð`), store it in the variable `D` and get the month (`g`). Why store it in the variable, if it's already one-letter? Because since then you can dress any part of date with `Da`, where `a` is the function, returning year, month, date, etc. But otherwise you'd have to do `Ð a`, see the space.
- `¥3` is `==3`, checking if the month is March.
- `©` is `&&`, i.e. "and".
- `Df` is the day of the month.
- `E` is 14
- `?...:...` - typical sets of ternary operators
- `Dd %C` the reminder of dividing the hour (`Dd`) by 12 (`C`)
- `Dc` is the minutes
- `Db` are seconds

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=RD3QKWcgpTOpRGYgpUU/IlBpIERheSI6RGQgJUOlM6lEYyClRT9gUGkgTYipZWA6RGMgpTOpRGIgpUU/YFBpIFNl1gg6Tm8gUGkgVItl&input=ImFiYyIgMTMgWzkgInp5eCJd)

---

[To emulate Pi Day:](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=RD3QIjMvMTQvMTEgMTE6MTE6MTEiOwpEZyClMqlEZiClRT8iUGkgRGF5IjpEZCAlQ6UzqURjIKVFP2BQaSBNiKllYDpEYyClM6lEYiClRT9gUGkgU2XWCDpObyBQaSBUi2U=&input=ImFiYyIgMTMgWzkgInp5eCJd)

```
D=Ð"3/14/11 11:11:11";
Dg ¥2©Df ¥E?"Pi Day":Dd %C¥3©Dc ¥E?`Pi M©e`:Dc ¥3©Db ¥E?`Pi SeÖ:No Pi Te
```

[To emulate Pi Minute](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=RD3QIjExLzExLzExIDM6MTQ6MTEiOwpEZyClMqlEZiClRT8iUGkgRGF5IjpEZCAlQ6UzqURjIKVFP2BQaSBNiKllYDpEYyClM6lEYiClRT9gUGkgU2XWCDpObyBQaSBUi2U=&input=ImFiYyIgMTMgWzkgInp5eCJd):

```
D=Ð"11/11/11 3:14:11";
Dg ¥2©Df ¥E?"Pi Day":Dd %C¥3©Dc ¥E?`Pi M©e`:Dc ¥3©Db ¥E?`Pi SeÖ:No Pi Te
```

[To emulate Pi Second](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=RD3QIjExLzExLzExIDAwOjM6MTQiOwpEZyClMqlEZiClRT8iUGkgRGF5IjpEZCAlQ6UzqURjIKVFP2BQaSBNiKllYDpEYyClM6lEYiClRT9gUGkgU2XWCDpObyBQaSBUi2U=&input=ImFiYyIgMTMgWzkgInp5eCJd):

```
D=Ð"11/11/11 00:3:14";
Dg ¥2©Df ¥E?"Pi Day":Dd %C¥3©Dc ¥E?`Pi M©e`:Dc ¥3©Db ¥E?`Pi SeÖ:No Pi Te
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 124 bytes

Thanks to FlagAsSpam for shaving a few bytes.

```
"→Str1
getTime
If min({3,14}={Ans(2),Ans(3
"Pi Second→Str1
getTime
If Ans(2)=14 and max(Ans(1)={3,14
"Pi Minute→Str1
getDate
If min({3,14}={Ans(2),Ans(3)
"Pi Day→Str1
Str1
```

Comment: Are you using _`i`_ (imaginary unit) and _`e`_ (Euler's constant) as shortcuts? If not, that could also save you some bytes.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I thought about using those, but I wasn't sure if it counts.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam Whether or not they're valid here, `e` is actually two bytes!

Comment: @ThomasKwa Oh, right.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam It is no longer invalid. ^_^

Comment: @FlagAsSpam Oh, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 80 - 15 = 65 bytes

```perl
print'No 'x localtime!~/(ar | 15:|03:)14/,'Pi ',(Time,Day,Minute,Second)["@-"/4]
```

Take 2, parsing the string representation of `localtime`. At present, this looks something like this:

```perl
Sun Jan  3 15:14:15 2016
```

The position of the matched string is used to determine the correct Pi Time.

---

#### Perl, 100 bytes

```perl
@t=localtime;$t[2]%=12;3-/3/^{@t[$_,$_+1]}->{14}||exit!print'Pi ',(Second,Minute,_,Day)[$_]for 3,1,0
```

`localtime` returns the months zero indexed, hence the need for `3-/3/`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1e](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 31 (46 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 15 bonus)

```
žfžeža12%žbDžc)2ôJƵÖk”€º‚Ž™Ù…Þ”#…Pi ìć…No ìªsè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L60o/tSj@5LNDRSPbovyeXovmRNo8NbvI5tPTwt@1HD3EdNaw7tetQw6@jeRy2LDs981LDs8DygsDKQEZCpcHjNkXYgyy8fyDq0qvjwiv//AQ) or [try it online with emulated datetime](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W@qoKCglJufV5KhFMNlaALkpCRWApkmIPGM/NKiYqUYFy5jsKrMvNKS1GKYuuLU5Py8FCD3v6bR4S1ex7Yenpb9qGHuo6Y1h3Y9aph1dO@jlkWHZz5qWHZ4HlBYGcgIyFQ4vOZIO5Dllw9kHVpVfHjF//8A).

Adding the `No Pi Time` bonus costed 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), so it's worth the -15. Here it is without the bonus:
`žfžeža12%žbDžc)2ôJƵÖk”‚Ž™Ù…Þ ”#„Pirèðý` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9vc2FiaWX//8W@ZsW@ZcW@YTEyJcW@YkTFvmMpMsO0Ssa1w5Zr4oCd4oCaxb3ihKLDmeKApsOeIOKAnSPigJ5QaXLDqMOww73//w) or [try it online with emulated datetime](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W@qoKCglJufV5KhFMNlaALkpCRWApkmIPGM/NKiYqUYFy5jsKrMvNKS1GKYuuLU5Py8FCD3v6bR4S1ex7Yenpb9qGHuo4ZZR/c@all0eOajhmWH5ykAhZQfNcwLyCw6vOLwhsN7//8HAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
žf               # Push the current month
  že             # Push the current day
ža               # Push the current hours (24-hours format)
  12%            # Modulo-12 to make it a 12-hours format
     žb          # Push the current minutes
D                # Duplicate the current minutes
 žc              # Push the current seconds
)                # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
 2ô              # Split it into pairs
   J             # Join each pair together
    ƵÖ           # Push compressed integer 314
      k          # Get the first 0-based index of 314 in this list (or -1 if none are)
”€º‚Ž™Ù…Þ”       # Push dictionary string "Time Day Minute Second"
          #      # Split it on spaces: ["Time","Day","Minute","Second"]
           …Pi ì # Prepend "Pi " in front of each:
                 #  ["Pi Time","Pi Day","Pi Minute","Pi Second"]
ć                # Extract head; pop and push remainder-list and first item separately
 …No ì           # Prepend "No " in front of it: "No Pi Time"
      ª          # Append it to the remainder-list:
                 #  ["Pi Day","Pi Minute","Pi Second","No Pi Time"]
s                # Swap so the earlier index of 314 is at the top
 è               # Use it to index into the list of strings,
                 # where -1 would get the last item
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”€º‚Ž™Ù…Þ”` is `"Time Day Minute Second"` and `ƵÖ` is `314`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 137 - 15 = 122 bytes

```
import time
T=list(time.localtime())
T[3]%=12
print({1:'Pi Day',3:'Pi Minute',4:'Pi Second'}.get(bytes(T[1:6]).find(b'\x03\x0e'),'No Pi Time'))
```

The 12-hour requirement was unfortunate, as this would've been 118-15=103 bytes without it:

```
import time
print({1:'Pi Day',3:'Pi Minute',4:'Pi Second'}.get(bytes(time.localtime()[1:6]).find(b'\x03\x0e'),'No Pi Time'))
```

Answer (score 2):

## AppleScript, <s>202</s> <s>190</s> <s>187</s> <s>183</s> 181 bytes

Hey, this isn't so bad after all.

```
set n to current date
set b to n's time string
if n's date string contains"March 14"
log"Pi Day"
else if b contains"3:14:"
log"Pi Minute"
else if b contains"3:14"
log"Pi Second"
end
```

<s>I actually found a use for AppleScript's method calling. Go figure.</s> Nope. Just turns out that `I'm an idiot`. Setting a variable is shorter.

(for those wondering, current date command returns a date-type with the contents `"Saturday, January 2, 2016 at 2:46:01 PM"` or the like)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 85 - 15 = 70 bytes

```
<?=['No Pi Time','Pi Day','Pi Minute','Pi Second'][strpos(@date(Ymdhi_is),'0314')/4];
```

---

The main trick use here is the `Ymdhi_is` [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), at the time of writing, `date('Ymdhi_is')` returns `201501030258_5828`.

- `md`, `hi` and `is` are the values who will be replaced by `0314` if it's Pi-something. Note that all those strings will be always be replaced by a 4-character long string.
- They are put in that specific order since `strpos` will stop searching at the first occurrence of the needle, so we put them in the order of priority.
- A separator between `hi` and `is` is necessary because we don't want `strpos` to match a value that would overlap both (thanks to [primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68371/pi-day-pi-minute-or-pi-second/68460#comment166273_68460) for saving bytes here).
- The needle is `0314` because `314` would wrongly match 10:31:42 as Pi-Second.

The Y part is the trickiest. We need a prefix to to offset the first occurrence of Pi-something, allowing us to distinguish `strpos`'s return values between `false` (not found, Pi-nothing) and `0` (found at index 0, Pi-day).

And we want this prefix to be either 4 or 5-character long, since we are planning to divide `strpos`'s return value by 4.

Y is 4-character long, but:

- it will be 5-character long someday, and this will break the program (think about year 10314): [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) says that `Y` will be replaced by 4 digits, but [it's not true](https://3v4l.org/N9MlD).
- if you come back in time, at year 314, it will break the program.

Since PHP didn't exist in year 314, and will likely not exist anymore in year 10314, I guess these bugs can be safely ignored.

Note that `0314` can overlap `Ymd` since:

- `Ymmd` configuration: there's no 31st month.
- `YYmm` configuration: there's no 14th month.
- `YYYm` configuration: there are less than 40 months.

---

Also, there's a version without the bugs related to the year, which is **86 - 15 = 71 bytes**:

```
<?=['No Pi Time','Pi Day','Pi Minute','Pi Second'][strpos(@date(D_mdhi_is),'0314')/4];
```

Comment: Great answer. If you use underscores rather than dots, you can drop the quotes around `Ymd_hi_is`. Also, I don't think a separator is necessary between `md` and `hi`, as the 12-hour `h` can never be 14, and never start with 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 226 Bytes

See also [FreePascal](/a/259162).
This `program` requires a processor complying to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.

```pascal
program p(output);var t:timeStamp;begin getTimeStamp(t);with t do write(subStr('Pi Day   ',1,9*ord(month=3))+subStr('Pi Minute',1,9*ord(hour in[3,15]))+subStr('Pi Second',1,9*ord(minute=3)):9*ord(14 in[day,minute,second]))end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program piDMS(output);
    var
        ts: timeStamp;
    begin
        getTimeStamp(ts);
        { `with t do ` is two characters shorter than six times `t.` }
        with ts do
        begin
            writeLn(
                    { subStr(string, firstCharacterIndex, length) }
                    subStr('Pi Day   ', 1, 9 * ord(month = 3)) +
                    subStr('Pi Minute', 1, 9 * ord(hour in [3,15])) + 
                    subStr('Pi Second', 1, 9 * ord(minute = 3))
                    : 9 * ord(14 in [day, minute, second])
                );
        end;
    end.
```

---

**216 characters** if

- the *implementation-defined* value of `maxChar` has an ordinal value ≥ 59 and
- neither `chr(3)` or `chr(14)` of the *implementation-defined* set of `char` values indicate an end of line (Pascal does not permit multiline strings).

```pascal
program p(output);var t:timeStamp;begin getTimeStamp(t);with t do year:=index(chr(month)+chr(day)+chr(hour mod 12)+chr(minute)+chr(second),'');write(subStr('Pi SecondPi Minute         Pi Day   ',37-9*t.year):9)end.
```

NB:
The `string` literal `''` is `chr(3) + chr(14)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 211 - 15 = 196 bytes

```go
import."time"
func f(){N,s:=Now(),"Pi "
M:=N.Minute()
if _,m,d:=N.Date();m==3&&d==14{s+="Day"}else if N.Hour()%12==3&&M==14{s+="Minute"}else if M==3&&N.Second()==14{s+="Second"}else{s="No "+s+"Time"}
println(s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY_BisIwEIbveYowoCS0FtQ9LEpuHrw0CLt3CW0qQZOUJkWk9Em8lAVv3vZRPPk2ts3inob5_49hvuvPwXb3UmRHcZBYC2VutS9mn8-H0qWtfAJeaQmoqE2GC0IbHrsV4_ZMaAw7hQGl_ZqkytReEopUgfexjvMh3IghWmvGltNpztj8o3ERg424QCtPTuIe5snW1hWhk_lixNI3Fk7-k-nY8-RLZtbkhL7BEASwcQy4xRC5CL6Hx1tUVsr4kyGOtkHtd3QZVAnFDeql0F_TdWG-AA)

Prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 45 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

:\ I can *definitely* do better than this! Outputs `undefined` if it's not a Pi date/time. Second line include a trailing space.

```
`DÃÕsMÔSSeÖ`qÅæÏgKs6 f"%d+" ã2)e#;ìF
©i"Pi
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YETD1XNNiNRTU2XWCGBxxebPZ0tzNiBmIiVkKyIg4zIpZSM77EYKqWkiUGkg), or test:

- [Pi Day](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=Sz3QS2kgMkUzRUU&code=YETD1XNNiNRTU2XWCGBxxebPZ0tzNiBmIiVkKyIg4zIpZSM77EYKVqlpIlBpIA)
- [Pi Minute](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=Sz3QS2kgMkQzRUU&code=YETD1XNNiNRTU2XWCGBxxebPZ0tzNiBmIiVkKyIg4zIpZSM77EYKVqlpIlBpIA)
- [Pi Second](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=Sz3QS2kgMkRBM0U&code=YETD1XNNiNRTU2XWCGBxxebPZ0tzNiBmIiVkKyIg4zIpZSM77EYKVqlpIlBpIA)

```
`...`qÅæÏgKs6 f"%d+" ã2)e#;ìF\n©i"Pi 
`...`                                     :Compressed string "DaysssMinutesSecond"
     q                                    :Split on
      Å                                   :  "s"
       æ                                  :Get first element to return true
        Ï                                 :When its index is passed through the following function
         g                                :  Index into
          K                               :    Date
           s6                             :    To locale string (M/D/Y, h:m:s A/PM)
              f                           :    Match
               "%d+"                      :      RegEx /\d+/
                     ã2                   :    Sub-arrays of length 2
                       )                  :  End indexing
                        e                 :  Is equal to
                         #;               :    59
                           ì              :    Converted to digit array in base
                            F             :      15
                             \n           :Assign to variable U
                               ©          :Logical AND with
                                i"Pi      :  U prepended with "Pi "
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>263</s> 229 bytes

```pascal
uses sysutils,RegExpr;var x:array[0..2]of string=('.*:03:14','.* 03:14.*','14-3.*');y:array[0..2]of string=('Second','Minute','Day');i:word;begin
for i:=0to 2do if ExecRegExpr(x[i],DateTimeToStr(Now))then writeln('Pi ',y[i]);end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY69DoIwFEZ3n@JugMEGf6YSNxg1Rt2MQ4UL3gRbcluEPj02xtXtfMk5ydcrW6lu1fTVPA8WLVhvB0edTc/YllPP@VsxTFIxK3/LhNjcTQPWMel2H0diKbOtXO@iNCB8USzDWO9W2wBJ7v@VF6yMroN6ID04DFAoHwKSo@E6f2BLetEYBpL7zBnY1AaogXLC6vcsnm50Twvl8EovvJqL4/hoxiRxT9QwMjnsdBydCKLUBzXJUddinj8)  
<sub><s>[263b](https://tio.run/##dY49b8IwFEX3/oq3xUbBCh@TrTDBWFQVNsTgJi/hSalt2Q6Jf31q0a7dztW9R7pOh0YP6841yzIGDBBSGCMNofzE/jQ7r57awyy19zrdKiG2d9tBiJ5MX7NCrGS1k5t9UWaEF4pVDpv9epeBq/SfecHGmjZP38mMETMcdcqCk78TRXKyvlVf2JN566wHknUVLWxbC9TBacbm7yKbb3Qvjzrilb7xai/Rs7OdOI8PNOBknXKvsjOg6eODOX6o4NVNniIOhhUfBEXpuELTimX5AQ)</s></sub>

<sub>Might be shortened by using `if..then..elseif..` instead of complicated arrays & loops.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 179 bytes

```
import functools as F,datetime as D
T,G=D.datetime.now(),getattr
F.reduce(lambda i,j:print("Pi "+i.title())if G(T,i)/G(T,j)==3/14else j,"month day hour minute second".split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/)*, <s>93</s> <s>88</s> 83 <sub>(98-15)</sub> bytes

```pascal
case `date` in *Mar\ 14*)t=Day;;*\ 03:14*)t=Minute;;*03:14\ *)t=Second;esac
<<<Pi\ ${t?No Pi Time}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5LC4JAFIbhvb/ioG1y5aULeKFFbQ0ho40LJ@dQAzlGc4Qs@u02aouo3cfLA@c81LlTSPWVAO@EkiM/XeqjYViEioCz1gLgsZk1CAm7gTsDdxH4y0CPfbYGz/F884MrIUd8QD7iOTi@loEev1hh@YddNxj8F@5KphAKzggLEBJsTXP9hT2leMPaMLTz8UYfEiEbQt2GkkPfdljWkoeoWGlEUZSKHCZPWm1rSAVkosJX170B) (98-15 bytes)
 <sub><s>[103-15 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc5NS8NAEAbge37FS1MoRoQm8QPygQe9eKgWTPGSQ9fsaBfMrs1O0Cr@9rjZeBA9zfDOM8x82N1gic0rg96ZtCT5/GIeAymYgiAEk2XszBuqmzs8ma4VbOGHoS84kVgcx4kzfWcXbsVvSHEIAVnOqp6wEh3iU8TnWXqRuWZTXSFZJunsB7dKT/iB5ITPsEydzFzzF1tq/uE4zrz/hYdGWMJ2fHELpRE5WrsvoiMur8Uhz6N6ujEGK6V7Jpf5pMaY3VNjtMzJiibYl2tVY/7Jl7cGa4VKtfSVF0Ux3w/DNw)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[93 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc5NS8NAEAbge37FS1MoRoRu4gfkgx704qEomOIlh67ZaRuwu212glbxt8fNxoPoaYZ3nmHmw@56S2wODHpn0orU9tW8BEoyBUEIJsvYmTeU9w/YmHYv2cIPQ19woTA7F7EzXWtnbsVvKHkKAVVMyo6wlC3EJcR1mtykrlmVt4jncTL5wftGj/iZ1IivME@cTF3zF1uq/2EhUu9/4b6WlrAeXlyj0YgcrdwX0RkXd/KUZVE13hiCZaM7Jpf5pMKQPVFttMrIyjo4Fo9NheknL76yPM@nx77/Bg)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[107-15 bytes, using associative array](https://tio.run/##dY5Na8JAEIbv@RXDmoMGAonRCmtCKfWqCEY8WME1O9ilmoRkFD/wt8elK6IGb@8Mz/txKn@rEinLCfBAmEqU6022sqwGYUkgxbEBUEQs3iEMRQF@B/wPHvS4FtP4G9peO2A3eKtSA89QGrgLXqBJrsUrXGJSg32f//M1WM9w9@49/2HMLf@d5d7yYnluqSQmG1EguF@QR03mGNJhMBBHYI5p0edQpTtC/TEz9WeCSZbKlkWRfc7nzb/WUgrC5eLSD8NwrH7APhP/HGUwVhCrLV6q6go)</s></sub>

Used `extendedglob` for matching the `case` patterns. If `$t` wasn't set (`${t?}`), then it prints "No Pi Time" to stderr.